# Why doesn't Visual Studio 2013 let me use Entity Framework 4?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to update my Object Context of a legacy project that we have. I don't know if it is a bug or something else, but even if we explicitly tell Visual Studio to use version 4 of EF, it updates to version 5 messing everything up. Always I have to go back to Visual Studio 2012 and make my changes. Is there a reason for that?

[image]

Comment: How are you explicitly telling it to use version 4?

Comment: Update wizard ask me which version I want to use before start.

Comment: Are you targeting .NET 4.0 or .NET 4.5?  Entity Framework 5.0 is automatically used if targeting .NET 4.5.

Comment: Yes, I'm. But it seems to be a bug, Am I wrong?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you targeting?  Is it 4.0, or is it 4.5?  And what version of entity framework are you updating from?

Comment: See this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5325334d-1b49-4c80-9f2e-b379815078c5/visual-studio-2013-ef-designer-and-ef-4-namespace-problem?forum=adodotnetentityframework and this SO question which might be relevant to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923156/how-to-use-entity-framework-4-with-visual-studio-2013

Answer (score 1):

-In Solution explorer in References remove the existing reference to Entity framework 5.

-In packages.config remove the line that has EntityFramework version 5

-In View->Other Windows -> Package Manager Console, paste the next line: 
***Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 4.1.10331.0***

It works in VS2012, hope it works in 2013 too.